# Shortest Job First Scheduling

Tags: operating-system, scheduling

Suppose that following processes arrive for the execution at the times indicated. Each process will run the listed amount of time.

```
Process [Arrival Time(ms) , Burst Time(ms)]
A[0 , 5] , B[3 , 5] , C[5 , 3] , D[7 , 2]
```

I want to draw *Gantt* chart and calculate average waiting time for preemptive Shortest *Job First* Scheduling.

Solution

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxXH5.jpg

Waiting Time is 2ms.

Just Please tell me if this is correct.

The step where I have doubt is that at 3ms when process B arrives, will the scheduler complete the process A or start process B.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Google, find, learn and then come for a focused clarification on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct. In fact the problem as posed is ambiguous, but both possibilities give the same answer.

First, the ambiguity : Shortest Job First scheduling is not usually considered preemptive. The preemptive variant is called Shortest Remaining Time First Scheduling (see for instance [the Shortest Job Next entry  on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_job_next). However, your exercice states "preemptive Job First scheduling", and *that's* ambiguous...

Second, however, the only time when there might be a difference between these two scheduling policies is, as you mentioned, at `t=3` when both A and B are eligible. But if the scheduling is non-preemptive, of course A continues to execute. It it's preemptive, we must consider the remaining time : A has 2 ms left while B has its whole 5... so A still gets the CPU.

Finally, the waiting times are : `A -> 0 ms, B -> 7 ms, C -> 0 ms, D -> 1ms`, the average of which is indeed `2 ms`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to do on your own your homework.

Show your try on that and say what are you questions and your issues.

Don't wait for a complete ready solution!

Comment: I have shared the solution link. Please verify the answer.

Comment: Well i think it's wrong. First of all you have drawn 16blocks but you have 15, 0-15 it's 16 so you go 0-14. Then when you reach an arrival time of another process then the process start you repeat until you finish with the processes at first time. Them you check again the remaining burst times and you start from the smallest. So to helo you will go normal until 9 and then you have to check.

Comment: Also that is not a Gantt chart but i think this is false of your teacher. So don't worry about that,but just to know.